# Bootstrap 4 Responsive Navbar Alignment

Tags: alignment, navbar, bootstrap-4

I been working with Bootstrap 4. I am having a problem where the menu doesn't appear aligned.

The example to this problem is here: http://www.bootply.com/xWjxonsmiz

There are three problems in the example (you can see it when you execute it)

1) The first issue (the sub-option-2 is not aligned to the center):

2) The second issue (when I resize the screen it does not appear aligned)

3) The third issue (when I resize the screen the 'Option 2' appears with some padding which I didn't set the same with the rest of the elements)

Where is the mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1) The first issue (the sub-option-2 is not aligned to the center):

The items in your dropdown meny  should not have the `.nav-link` and `.nav-item` classes (these classes set a left margin for any `na.nav-link + .nav-link`).:
In _navbar.scss:

```
.nav-link
 + .nav-link {
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
}
```

The above possible also cause your third issue. I do not understand your second issue, but i do also wonder if BS4 support navbar dropdowns already?

**update**
Also read 
[Bootstrap 4’s responsive navbars](http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/bootstrap-4s-responsive-navbars/) about navbar dropdowns and justified navbar items. See also https://github.com/bassjobsen/responsive-navbar-dropdowns for an example of navbar dropdown menus.